# How to make Skype use notify-osd?

Tags: skype, scripts, notify-osd

How do I make Skype use the default Ubuntu notify-osd to display notifications (incoming messages, users connecting, etc.) instead of the Skype's own "ugly" message box?

Comment: There is a bug report against Skype at https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCL-502, however it hasn't received much attention and is growing dusty.

Comment: Note that you must have Empathy installed and at least one telepathy account set up before you can set your status or have things be driven by your status.  I've filed a bug on this:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/994607

Answer (score 24):

Try

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

then go to skype options, notification settings, find event you want to edit (for example, online contact notification), check "Execute following script" and insert

```
notify-send "%sname is now online" -i skype
```

This worked for me. You can do this with other notifications as well.

Comment: This is awesome! It is so simple and yet it is exactly what I wanted! This should be an accepted answer.

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/gD9KeJCX) you can find a list of the available parameters like `%sname`.

Comment: Thx @Jakob - without that link the answer isn't worth half as much.

Comment: Skype now has option to use built in notifier.  v4.3

Answer (score 14):

There is a tool called Skype-wrapper that uses native notification system of Ubuntu.

To install Skype-wrapper, enter the following commands in a terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper python-skype
```

**Note:** The above PPA, at the time of writing, has packages for 10.10, 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04 only.

After installing skype-wrapper, open Skype and sign in. Then, open skype-wrapper and allow it to use Skype by clicking the 'Yes' button. Select the option "Remember this selection" if you don't want to repeat this step everytime you use skype-wrapper.

[image]

After authorizing skype-wrapper to use Skype, you will have both native notifications and Skype's actual notifications. To disable Skype's notifications, open Skype and go to options > notifications and disable all of the available notification types. Disabling notifications inside Skype doesn't disable skype-wrapper's native notifications.

[image]

Useful link:
[How to add Skype to the Ubuntu messaging-menu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/how-to-add-skype-to-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/)

Comment: Is Skype-Wrapper only a good solution for Ubuntu systems using Unity? Or will it work fine for Ubuntu with Gnome 3 desktops as well?

Comment: I haven't tried it on other desktop environments. But I am quite sure it is tailored for Unity given it ties Skype with the indicator-message and what not.

Comment: In my opinion it works decently for Gnome in 12.04

Answer (score 3):

Another work-around: install Pidgin, make sure Pidgin has a Skype account, then everything will go directly to notify-osd. (Downside: you have to then have both Pidgin and Skype open.)

Integration [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9065/how-to-integrate-skype-into-pidgin).

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution based on another answer on this question:

```
sudo apt-get install libnotify-bin
```

then go to skype options -> notification settings and find the event you want to edit (for example, online contact notification) and click advanced view.

Next, check "Display built-in system pop-up notification"

You can do this with other events as well.