# Is there an alternative to the skype service?

Tags: 13.04, skype, voip

On ubuntu 13.04 Skype segfaults constantly (I've read a couple of threads about fixing the issue and it is kind of works now expect it segfaults every time chat message comes in) so I'm thinking it is time to find it a replacement.

Which one should I choose?

Ok, I've seen previous post, yet only one answer in it highlights some alternatives. Also I want no the alternative skype client, but the whole ecosystem.

The one alternative presented ooVoo does not support linux and other goober shows unresolved dependency: libglew1.5

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/120751/is-there-an-alternative-skype-client

Comment: @kingmilo I've seen this thread. The one alternative presented ooVoo does not support linux and other goober shows unresolved dependency: libglew1.5

Comment: There are 4/5 alternatives there including using Pidgin have you tried them all? If you get an unresolved dependency then perhaps you should troubleshoot resolving that required dependency - http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libglew1.5 It looks like the latest version of that is 1.8 but you could compile the exact version you need yourself for example, or look into the other alternatives provided in that thread. You could also bring up your concerns in that thread as to avoid duplicates :)

Comment: @kingmilo >>using Pidgin<<< 
I've done with skype for good (it was buggish and unstable as far as I remember)  and I'm seeking replacement. >>you could compile the exact version you need yourself<<< No, I can't because they do not provide source code. They provide only packages and binaries. There is no other alternatives in that thread whatsoever, also that thread was about alternative skype clients and I'm looking for alternative to skype services or platforms, hence new thread.

Comment: The source code can be found here: http://glew.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @kingmilo I cannot recompile goober not glew.

Comment: You said you have a missing dependency, libglew1.5 - you need to compile glew from source, then try and recompile goober.

Comment: @kingmilo Not sure I got it. How do I recompile goober if no source for goober present? Or should I just compile old version of libglew and put in in places goober expects to find?

Comment: Yes, compile the version of `libglew.*` you need and then try and reinstall `goober` as you did earlier. You shouldn't have to move libglew but if goober is looking for it in a different location then create a **symlink** rather than move it  :)

Answer (score 1):

[Reflap](http://www.reflap.com) is great [skype alternative](http://www.reflap.com/skype-alternative) out there. It's web based so you won't need to download anything and you can make free video calls to anyone of your choice easily. Plus you get a call address which will serve as your phone number allowing anyone to call you when your available.