# How do I install Tox?

Tags: software-installation, tox

Apparently [Tox](https://tox.chat/) is a free and secure replacement of Skype. I like it, but, how do I install it?

Comment: Please note: This s NOT about the Python test runner [`tox`](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). That one can be installed with `sudo apt-get install tox`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Tox has a new website called [tox.chat](https://tox.chat/). The old `tox.im` is no more.  **That is no longer the official site**.

---

> How do I install Tox?

### Manually

You can download Tox binaries from the [Tox Binaries](https://wiki.tox.chat/binaries) page. Choose the package that is appropriate for your system. When downloaded, install like so:

```
 sudo dpkg -i {YOUR_PREFERRED_TOX_CLIENT}.deb
```

After that, search for the client you just installed.

### <s>PPA</s>

**As of 23 February 2018, Debian and Ubuntu package repository has been [shut down](https://blog.tox.chat/2018/02/shutdown-of-the-debian-and-ubuntu-package-repository/).** The section below is preserved for its historic value.

Warning: They recently changed their PPA infrastructure, remove keys and the likes, as they are no longer maintained and supported.

The new way to install (currently only 64-bit qTox is supported):

```
echo "deb https://pkg.tox.chat/debian nightly $(lsb_release -cs)" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tox.list
wget -qO - https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/pkg.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install qtox
```

The `release` channel is no longer receiving updates so do not set the channel to just `release`, `qtox-unity` is also no longer receiving support so you can now only install `qtox` from still supported channels such as `wily`.

**Please note** though that if you have the `release` channel set simply changing that won't work, if you do change it to something like `wily` the upgrade link will be broken and you will not recieve any updates for `qtox` until you remove it, update your sources list (`sudo apt-get update`), and then install it from the correct channel.

Also, a note from a qtox developers:

> "To reiterate irungentoo’s reply in that thread, yes you should
>   uninstall any repos from tox.im, and you should not trust any new
>   binaries from tox.im or libtoxcore.so. We have a new repo:
>   https://wiki.tox.chat/binaries#gnulinux
>
> Right now only qTox is in it, but we’re working on getting the rest of
>   the clients up.
>
> Just a note, we have no reason to believe that any binaries from the
>   old repo/domains have been compromised. This is just a safety measure." - [Current Situation | Tox Blog#comment 14](https://blog.tox.chat/2015/07/current-situation-3/#comment-14)

#### qtox

[image: Ubuntu 14.04, qtox]
<sup>Ubuntu 14.04, qtox</sup>

#### toxic

[image: toxic, terminal based tox client]

<sup>toxic, terminal based tox client</sup>

---

What is [Tox](https://tox.chat/)? Tox is a skype replacement, with downloads available for Linux/Mac/Windows. At the time of writing, there are `deb` packages for `AMD64` downloads, portage overlays and Arch Linux PKGBUILD's, as per the Tox [Binaries](https://wiki.tox.chat/binaries) page. If one wishes to keep an eye out of the progress Tox is making, one could check out there [GitHub page](https://github.com/irungentoo/toxcore).

> Project Tox, also known as Tox, is a FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) instant messaging application aimed to replace Skype.

Why does Tox exist?

> With the rise of governmental monitoring programs, Tox aims to be an easy to use, all-in-one communication platform (including audio, and videochats in the future) that ensures their users full privacy and secure message delivery.

About Tox

> Tox is built with the idea that you can keep up with friends and family without having your privacy violated. While other big-name services require you to pay to unlock features, Tox is free in both price, and in liberty. That is, you’re free to do whatever you wish with Tox.

---

**Video**

QTox running under Ubuntu Trusty Tahr 14.04.

- [Tox, the free and secure skype replacement - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmz9I_FPB2M)

---

**Reference:**

- [Tox, the free and secure skype replacement - EuroBytes](http://www.eurobytes.nl/tutorials/tox-the-free-and-secure-skype-replacement)
- [tox.chat: Tox homepage](https://tox.chat/)
- [github.com: irungentoo/toxcore](https://github.com/irungentoo/toxcore)
- [binaries - Tox Wiki](https://wiki.tox.chat/binaries)

Comment: The qTox developers are [no longer making it available through the official repositories](https://github.com/tux3/qTox/issues/3184#issuecomment-218484141). So you should update your answer accordingly (they are forcing us to use community builds).

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu package repository has been shut down apparently: https://blog.tox.chat/2018/02/shutdown-of-the-debian-and-ubuntu-package-repository/.