# What is the best video communicator for Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, video

Which video calls client do you think is the best, and has compatibility for Ubuntu and Windows 8?

Comment: You can give tox a try, be warned tho, its early alpha: http://askubuntu.com/q/423716/36315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no best answer - you have to find the option it best suits you. We all have different tastes and needs.

If you are looking for an open-source video call client whith runs under Ubuntu and Windows, you can try Jitsi.