# Can someone help me escape Skype and use Ekiga?

Tags: skype, authentication, sip, ekiga

I really want to escape from Skype because its Linux support is abysmal and its ethics questionable. The most prominent alternative seems to be Ekiga, but I just can't get it working. Could someone help?

I've installed Ekiga and signed up for a free Ekiga SIP account. When I run Ekiga and attempt to call the echo test number sip:500@ekiga.net listed [here](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Fun_Numbers), I have been presented with various messages such as "Security check failed" and "Globally not accepted".

I've looked at [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ekiga/+bug/120251) old but still active bug report and tried adding myself to the voice user group with no success.

Could anyone guide me on this? I've no idea what to do.

Comment: Another alternative for Skype is Tox. It uses fully end-to-end encrypted P2P traffic without servers and is both free and open-source. Unfortunately, it is still in beta stage, but already well usable. There exist numbers of clients like qTox, µTox, Toxic,... for most OS. [See this question for more information](http://askubuntu.com/q/423716/367990).

Comment: You might be interested that Skype has announced beta version of [Skype for Web](http://blogs.skype.com/2014/11/14/please-welcome-skype-for-web-beta/) making it available only through Internet browser.

Comment: @ByteCommander Wow, I tried Tox about a year ago without much success, but it got good! It even has video now. Thank you for the suggestion; I'm using qTox now.

Comment: @VRR Thank you for your suggestion on Skype for Web. Currently it blocks Linux devices from accessing it and when I pretend to be using Windows (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/59/), it announces that it is available by invite only. Obviously it is quite new, but it is not usable at this time (and it still leaves the ethics of Skype to contend with).

Comment: Oh, the ethics!  My bet they are only implementing this feature because Firefox announced video chat recently.

Comment: I found that I got this error when calling the Ekiga numbers, but calling normal phone numbers worked.