# How to delete qTox profile?

Tags: qtox

I have installed qTox using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/423717/364819), however I have forgotten my password and wish to create a new profile, but also delete the old one. And this is where I have my problem, I have tried purging it and then installing it again, however that does not seem to delete the profile? So how do I delete it? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and the latest version of qTox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply nuke it all

```
rm -rf .config/tox/
```

Comment: What about the file @hg8 talks about?

Comment: The `tox-username.tox` file is the correct one, so I'd say his answer is better in exactness, mine is better in simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove your profile files :

```
rm ~/.config/tox/<tox_username>.tox
rm ~/.config/tox/qtox.ini
```

Comment: What about the files @Serg talks about?

Comment: If you just want to create a new profile on the same computer (and for the same person), with the same username there is no need to delete your history :)