# What does it mean to make Tox "portable"?

Tags: configuration, portable, tox, qtox

I have recently followed [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/423717/364819) and installed qTox, and I have noticed this section in the settings:

[image]

So what does it mean to make Tox "portable", and why is this something potentially dangerous to do (or is the warning notice not referring to this, but instead what is below it)? I mean I know you can already export your profile to other Tox clients on other machines, so what does it mean to also make it "portable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hover the mouse over that text, it says that config files will be saved in `$(PWD)` where you run tox rather than in `$HOME/.config`. For example, if my `qtox` executable is on Desktop, the configs will be on Desktop.

This makes it easier to transport qTox as it will put everything in one place (folder).