# How to tunnel Tox through Tor?

Tags: tor, privacy, tox

I recently installed qTox using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/423717/364819), but as I read in the Tox FAQs that [Tox doesn't actually make any attempt to cloak your IP](https://wiki.tox.chat/users/faq#does_tox_leak_my_ip_address), I was wondering as it mentioned:

> A workaround does exist in the form of tunneling your Tox connections through Tor.

How exactly you can use Tor with Tox? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and the latest version of qTox.

Comment: AFAIK, when you connect to TOR, all of your internet traffic is forwarded through it, much like a VPN connection.

Comment: @HeatherBrown: Well, I don't want that, I only want my Tox traffic to go through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Torify](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/torify.1.html). Torify is a wrapper for TOR and TORSocks which applies TOR to a specific application.

```
sudo apt-get install tor torsocks
torify command/or/path/to/tox
```

Comment: I tried to install that but it says it can't find the package...

Comment: Possibly part of the `tor` package itself...