# How do I install qtox in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, qtox

I followed the steps as in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423716/how-do-i-install-tox).But it didn't help.
I went to this [link](https://tox.chat/download.html#gnulinux),selected "Debian/Ubuntu" and executed all those commands and I get the following output.

[image]
In the [link](https://tox.chat/download.html#gnulinux) it has been mentioned that only Ubuntu Vivid and Wily are officially supported.
Is that the reason why I get the above output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the repository that you linked to, `qtox-unity` is indeed not available for Ubuntu 16.04. However, you can still install the qTox client for Tox following the instructions at https://github.com/tux3/qTox and https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Aantonbatenev%3Atox&package=qtox:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/antonbatenev:/tox/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qtox.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtox
```

If you want, you can also add the repository key to APT:

```
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:antonbatenev:tox/xUbuntu_16.04/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key
```

Comment: Sadly it's gone too. Anton deleted it.

Comment: @expert That's unfortunate.