# Skype using Notify-OSD

Tags: skype, notify-osd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Skype use notify-osd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8918/how-to-make-skype-use-notify-osd)

is there any working way setup skype to using Notify-OSD? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and latest Skype from repositories (2.2.0.35).

Thanks for answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't found it during search for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project called [skype-wrappers](https://launchpad.net/~skype-wrapper/+archive/ppa) which not only does what you want but also integrates skype into messaging menu. [Here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/skype-wrapper-0-4-adds-unity-features-menu-avatars-and-extra-settings/) is a blog on its feature.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skype-wrapper/ppa`
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype-wrapper
```

If you just want notification, install `libnotify-bin` and follow the [instructions](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/skype-libnotify-linux/).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. It seems that this is what I need, but it have some issues. I don't have Skype-wrapper in dash so i need execute it from terminal. I cannot add skype-wrapper it into unity. Any help with that?

Comment: just do alt+f2 and run skype-wrapper

Comment: Any way how to add this in Launcher?

Comment: open your `/usr/share/applications` and drag and drop `skype-wrapper.desktop` to the launcher. Basically, both Skype and skype-wrapper are named as skype, so unity dash won't show two instances.